# ValueConveter or DataTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, converters

I am trying to build a generic interface that can accept a List of objects and then based on the users selection of how they want to view the objects will select different ways of display the object. Currently, the user has a dropdown that allows them to choose the view type such as "Details, Previews, etc" much like explorer and then based off the selection the display should change. My first attempt at this was to create UserControls that will accept the bound object and display it, however I dont know how to convert my listitems into the user controls. My question is, is should I be using IValueConverter to convert the listitem into the type of user control I want to display, or should I be using DataTemplates and a TemplateSelector to define my different views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use ListView and GridView? Your use case is exactly why they're there.

MSDN has a nice little sample for how to switch views in a ListView at runtime right [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771469.aspx).

Comment: I will read about that. My thinking was that in the future I want to use these same views in other parts of the application, which is why I tried to make controls out of the items.

Comment: That's not too difficult. Create a bunch of styles and stick them in a styles.xaml file, and use them all over your application. This principle applies not only for ListView and GridView, but your entire application in general :)